# Mac screen shows apple logo and cursor, then black

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

It seems my mac has some physical damage to the screen with a small crack near an edge.  However, when I reboot it, the white apple logo shows perfectly and a bit later for a few second I can see the white cursor and move it about the screen.

I would just make do and use my mac as it is, I can deal with a little crack.  However, once it gets to the login screen, the screen goes black.  I am able to plug in an external monitor and use the mac with the external monitor, but I would like to use my original screen as well. Thus my situation is different from this one:
[MacBook Pro boots to black screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259642/macbook-pro-boots-to-black-screen)

I can't seem to find anyone with the exact same experience online.  For example, my computer is actually booting up. I am even submitting this question using it!  So it is different from the following:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5984310

The closest exprience is this one, but it does not mention the apple logo appearing on the native monitor or the cursor.  Also there is no mention of damage to the screen.  I have tried the SMC reset and it does not seem to work.
[Black Screen on MacBook Pro A1278](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259455/black-screen-on-macbook-pro-a1278)

I tried rebooting multiple times.

I tried to play with the display settings (resolution etc) to see if I could get the screen to display.  Nothing even makes it flicker.  When I adjust the brightness, there does seem to be a change in the backlight brightness behind the black.

It seems to me the screen had detected it has an error and switched itself off.... but it seems usable.  Is there anyway to bypass this and use the screen as it is?  Any settings (including terminal commands) that I could use?

Every once in a white the screen will flash for some miliseconds an image of what I should be seeing. (This makes me wonder if the only solution is a new screen, yet the mac symbol didn't flash, it stayed up, so I have hope there may be some software solution.)

I am using a MacBook Air.

Comment: With the external screen connected at boot, what do you see on that **as** the Mac is booting?

Comment: The external screen is black when booting (when the apple logo and progress bar appear on the laptop screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a photo of the damaged screen we may be guessing if that is relevant. I would follow the startup article twice before seeking repair assistance. First do this with absolutely nothing connected to the Mac.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156

Then repeat with a display connected only (assuming your Mac has enough charge to run).

Comment: I thought I had already restarted with every combination.  1) restarted with nothing connected—no improvement and then 2) restarted with only the external monitor connected, but no power supply.  To my surprise the native screen started working again!

Comment: There is also the possibility that when I cleaned the screen to take a photo the light pressure on the screen is part of what fixed the problem. I was doing that at the same time as my final restart.